# watercolor templates

Tags: watercolor

I'm looking for books consisting only of watercolor templates in a fixed format. These might be famous paintings or a theme-specific collection. I do not want books with explaining texts or painting on mixed media. The closest thing I found so far are postcard collections, but those are often not watercolors. Background: I have a hard time finding a motivation to paint. With such a book, I would copy them one by one (at least in theory...).

Comment: What do you mean by "watercolor template"... Is that like a paint by numbers thing, outlines to be filled in? Or are you looking for collections of watercolors to use a reference?

Comment: Good point. I mean the latter, just a collection of watercolor paintings.

Comment: Afraid it is still a problematic question for the site as it is general and opinion based. I would recommend going to bookstores and libraries and looking at the art books. There are plenty of artists that work in watercolors with catalogs of their works out there. Plus you may find inspiration outside of watercolorists.

Comment: can you give specific examples? I have a hard time finding such books. All I find at book stores and online are how-to-paint-guides and biography-like-art-books with plenty of text between a handful of small paintings.